# routing resources with a wild card

Tags: phoenix-framework

I have this routing

```
scope "/api", MosaicApi do
      pipe_through :api

    #   resources "/cards", CardController, except: [:new, :edit]
      resources "/estimates/:product", EstimateController, except: [:new, :edit]
```

Initially I used the generated CardController and things worked (at least POST/create did), but now I want to generalise as Card is a product type and I have a variety of other products that need to expose the exact same CRUD operations. So I am trying to morph Card* to Estimate*

In EstimateController I now have this

```
defmodule Api.CardController do
  use Api.Web, :controller

  alias Api.Card

  def create(conn, %{"product" => product}) do
      conn
      |> render("result.json", product: product)
  end
  ...
```

What I want to do is pattern match on product to bring into scope the relevant Struct (Card, ...), but I've got stuck as the code above yields this error

> undefined function Api.EstimateController.init/1 (module Api.EstimateController is not available)
>           Api.EstimateController.init(:create)

I'm confused as `init` is not mentioned in http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/controllers at all

Other indications that things are mostly good

```
mix phoenix.routes
    page_path  GET     /                            Api.PageController :index
estimate_path  GET     /api/estimates/:product      Api.EstimateController :index
estimate_path  GET     /api/estimates/:product/:id  Api.EstimateController :show
estimate_path  POST    /api/estimates/:product      Api.EstimateController :create
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `init/1` is defined in https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.1.4/lib/phoenix/controller/pipeline.ex#L98

```
  def init(action) when is_atom(action) do
    action
  end
```

It looks like you are not calling `use Phoenix.Controller` in your `EstimatesController`.

Usually this is done with:

```
use Api.Web, :controller
```

Comment: But now I see I forgot to change the name of the module - igore my quesiton